# Come tradurre "distinguished bilinear form"?

Tags: word-choice, translation, mathematics

Nel libro di Hofer-Zehnder, Symplectic Invariants and Hamiltonian Dynamics, ad un certo punto si dice "distinguished bilinear form", e più avanti "distinguished symplectic invariant". Il senso di "distinguished" pare essere "particolare, specificato, distinto, speciale, specifico". Mi chiedevo se ci fossero altri modi (magari migliori di questi) per tradurre questo aggettivo in Italiano. Qualcuno ha qualche idea?

**Update**

Questi sono alcuni esempi di uso di "distinguished" in questo senso tratti dall'Hofer. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XL3gp.jpg), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LseVa.jpg), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpllS.jpg), [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7rEa.jpg), [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twlYY.jpg), [6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKue7.jpg), [7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i09Da.jpg).

Comment: “Speciale” suonerebbe bene, se non fosse che suona così bene che si usa già per altre cose (i gruppi SL(*n*, *q*) e simili) che penso non c'entrino qui. È possibile dire in due parole a che si riferisce la “distinzione”?

Comment: @DaG Suppongo che si tratti di distinguere quella forma dal mare magnum delle possibili forme bilineari, o quell'invariante da tutti gli altri.

Comment: Sarebbe necessario avere tutte le due frasi complete per capire se la forma bilineare è "speciale" o "particolare". La differenza sta nel fatto che se fosse speciale lo sarebbe sempre, mentre userei particolare se fosse riferito al caso specifico.

Comment: Per capire: il testo dà una definizione di “distinguished bilinear form” con certe proprietà in più rispetto a una forma bilineare qualsiasi, oppure all'interno di un discorso dice qualcosa come “...e ora prendiamo in esame una ben precisa forma bilineare”?

Comment: @DaG vedi Update.

Comment: E anche @RiccardoI.

Comment: Ah, d'accordo. Allora io direi “specifico, ben preciso”.

Comment: Sono d'accordo. "Specifico, particolare, che contraddistingue" quella classe di elementi

Comment: Direi che "ben preciso" is the way to go, perché "specifico" sarebbe confuso con "specific", e "che contraddistingue" è un po' lunghetto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A naso io userei "una data forma bilineare" oppure "una fissata forma bilineare" per tradurre "a distinguished bilinear form". E.g. il primo esempio che viene dato nella domanda lo tradurrei con

"Uno spazio vettoriale simplettico è uno spazio vettoriale finito dimensionale insieme ad una data forma bilineare che è antisimmetrica e non degenere"

o

"Uno spazio vettoriale simplettico è uno spazio vettoriale finito dimensionale insieme ad una fissata forma bilineare che è antisimmetrica e non degenere"

(Grazie a @Dag per il suggerimento di usare "fissata" invece di "data" che è molto più pulito)

Comment: Oppure “...una fissata forma bilineare...”.

Comment: A posteriori il suggerimento di @DaG è migliore. Il mio viene da una traduzione letterale dell'inglese "given", che è usato in inglese più comunemente di "distinguished" in questo contesto

Comment: Inseriscilo pure nella tua risposta, Denis, così rimane tutto insieme.

Answer (score 3):

Nel senso usato da Hofer e Zehnder in tutti i luoghi menzionati,  "distinguished" si riferisce ad un oggetto scelto e fissato una volta per tutte, che definisce una struttura matematica, o che comunque è associato canonicamente ad essa. Si tratta di un uso abbastanza comune nell'inglese matematico. Per fare un esempio ancora più elementare: "A pointed set is a set together with a distinguished element, called the base point."

In questo senso l'italiano matematico usa comunemente "fissato", "assegnato", o anche "dato". *"Uno spazio vettoriale simplettico è uno spazio vettoriale reale di dimensione finita munito di una forma bilineare fissata, antisimmetrica e non degenere".*  Si può anche omettere del tutto, così come nelle altre lingue.